# Describing the motion of a point-mass

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, kinematics, angular-velocity

Consider a point-mass moving around a fixed point on a circle with radius $r$ with constant angular velocity $\omega$. At a certain moment of time, the connection is removed, and the point-mass flies away tangentially to the circle.

I need to describe this motion in the inertial frame (where the point-mass is rotating in the beginning) and in a reference frame rotating with angular velocity $\omega$ around the fixed point (where the point-mass is at rest in the beginning). How can I do that?

Comment: In a rotating frame of reference, "fictitious forces" appear. In particular, your particle will appear to feel centrifugal and Coriolis forces. If you are expected to answer this question you should already know what these things are - and so you should be able to write the equation of motion of the particle in the rotating frame of reference (as usual, acceleration = force / mass; in this case, "force" is fictitious).

Comment: Possible duplicate, "Rotation systems. Problem interpreting an equation" http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/148944/rotation-systems-problem-interpreting-an-equation/149237#149237