# Force and direction of velocity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

If the angle between force acting on a particle  and velocity of particle is zero degree, the value of velocity will increase. If this angle is 180 degree, the value of velocity will decrease. If this angle is 90 degree, value remains constant, but direction will change. The process of changing value of velocity can be determined easily. When two same vectors act at different angle on a particle, the value and direction of resultant vector can be determined easily by using formula. How and by which formula  the direction of velocity will be determined, if force acts with velocity at right angle?

Comment: You mean direction of initial velocity.?

Comment: circular motion?

Answer (score 3):

Considering motion in a 2D plane:

If the resultant force acts perpendicular to the velocity, the force's magnitude will be equal to:

$$F = \frac{mv^2}{R}$$

Where $R$ is the radius of curvature of particle's trajectory, and $v$ is the speed.

Note that, as long as the force is perpendicular to the velocity, the speed will not increase. This is because no work is ever being done on the particle by the force. This arises from the definition of work: the product of the displacement and the component of force in the direction of the displacement. This can be expressed as:

$$W = \int^t_0 \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{r}$$

Here, the force is perpendicular to any displacement that is made, so no component of the force ever lies in the direction of the displacement, so no work is done. In the equation, the force, $\vec F$, is perpendicular to an infinitesimal displacement, $d \vec r$, at that time, so $\vec F \cdot d \vec r = 0$. Therefore $W$ is zero.

By the work-energy principle, no work means no change in kinetic energy. Therefore, the speed is constant.

The rate of change of rotation, the angular velocity, $\omega$ is defined as:

$$\omega = \frac{v}{R}$$

By substitution, it turns out that:

$$\omega = \frac{F}{mv}$$

There, we can find the angle $\theta$ that the velocity occurs in (the direction) using:

$$\theta = \theta_0+\int^t_0 \omega dt = \theta_0+\frac{1}{mv}\int^t_0 F dt$$

Where $\theta_0$ is the initial direction of velocity. For a constant magnitude for force,

$$\theta = \theta_0 + \frac{F}{mv} t$$

Note that if the magnitude of force differs, you will not get a circular orbit.

Further, this problem becomes much more complex whenever the motion not long occurs within just a 2D plane.

Comment: I apologize, but you didn't say much. You see, F is not only a function of t, but also of v. As Phonix asked, whether it is a circular motion, if the answer is "yes" then F is adjusted at any moment to be perpendicular on v. So, F(t) is not known to us. It's complicated: it depends on v, and v depends on F. I also have to modify my answer.

Comment: That is based on the assumption that you want the motion to occur for an arbitrarily selected radius of curvature, which constrains the force, forcing it to depend on the velocity. However, no such thing was said, so I assumed that the force is arbitrarily selected as a function of time. As for circular motion, if force magnitude is constant, it will ALWAYS result in circular motion regardless of what magnitude of the force is selected. Simply other radii of curvature are produced.

Comment: An analogy that I had in mind was a rocket in space (far from other planets), firing its rockets perpendicular to its trajectory at an arbitrary force. That is, you have full control in defining the force as a function of time. I realise that full control in resultant force is not as easy in most other physical systems, but this is just my perspective in the matter.

Comment: you have a problem in your last equation: $|v|$ is not constant in time, as $|F|$ is not constant in time. You can't escape it. In all the velocity at a certain time is not tangential to the radius. The problem, if $|F|$ is not constant in time, is iterative. On the other hand, if $|F|$ is constant in time, the problem is trivial and was solved at see "Rotation systems. Problem interpreting an equation".

Comment: your formula $\omega = v/R$ is wrong, because $\vec v$ is not guaranteed to be tangential to the radius. To work in a rotating frame of coordinates, this won't be a simple frame, because you have all the time to adjust the axes s.t. one of them be perpendicular to the velocity.

Comment: Please note that $R$ is not the radius, but it is the instantaneous radius of curvature, which, at a particular point in the trajectory, must be perpendicular to the velocity.

Comment: I can note that, but it won't help much, practically. $v$ that you leave outside the integral over time, is time-dependent. You integrate $\omega$ over time, but what is the function $\omega(t)$, can you say? In the same equality, in the first integral $v$ is under the integral, while in the 2nd integral you leave $v$ outside. But $v$ depends on time because $F$ does. So, in addition, you leave us with integrands that we don't know their expressions.

Comment: $v$, the tangential speed, does not depend on time. Why? The force is always perpendicular to it, so the force never does work on the particle. No work, no change in KE, so, constant speed.

Comment: it were better to express everything, $v$, $\omega$ as functions of $F(t)$. But then, what to do with the length $R$? It is not constant. This is why I rejected the idea of working with a rotating system.

Comment: Also, note that $\omega$ varied because the instantaneous radius of curvature changes wrt time. Is it possible you are confusing this coordinate system (intrinsic) with polar coordinates?

Comment: I don't confuse, but I am having a problem with the perpendicularity of the force. See how the force works: first of all it creates a velocity component along itself, perpendicular to the velocity. So, they are no more perpendicular to one another. **After that** the force adjusts itself to be perpendicular to the new velocity.

Comment: I am looking at my equations (4) and (5). They tell me that $v$ is changing in magnitude. Do you find something wrong in them? I can't say that your answer is wrong, but I have doubts. My answer is maybe complicated, but I suppose nothing that can raise doubts - so I think.

Comment: Yes, but the time step that such a change in velocity takes place is infinitesimal, so the rotation that stop the force being perpendicular is also infinitesimal. Besides, that's a discrete way of thinking of this motion, but this motion is continuous, and so the "updating" of the acceleration is instantaneous. If your complaint is that the acceleration can't possibly respond instantly, then that's because that's an assumption I made to keep the calculation practically simple. Is that what the problem was?

Comment: I think that you are right and I would gladly upvote you. But please, would you be so kind to introduce in your answer the explanation with the constant kinetic energy because the force is perpendicular to velocity? It is the argument that convinced me. And please, can you notify me after doing this?

Comment: won't you accept my proposal to introduce that convincing argument about force perpendicular to velocity won't modify the energy, because no mechanical work? I would be glad to upvote you.

Comment: Answer modified! :)

Comment: I upvoted you. Congratulations for the simple and elegant answer.

Answer (score 1):

As the force acting in certain direction produce acceleration only  in that direction, if force act perpendicular to the velocity it can produce an additional velocity component in perpendicular direction only. you should also consider the fact that as no force act in direction of original velocity component its value remains unchanged. Thus the resulting velocity is vector sum of these two velocities. However saying the force is acting perpendicular to velocity has many interpretations. One case is that force remains always perpendicular to velocity .This will be case of circular motion. Let me explain this: Initially you have a force acting perpendicular to velocity giving rise to a perpendicular velocity component and thus the resultant  of two is a velocity turned inwards to initial velocity but at the next instant the force changes its direction so it again becomes perpendicular to this resultant velocity. Another case is the velocity is perpendicular to the initial direction of velocity and with time the perpendicular component of velocity grows and resultant of this growing perpendicular velocity and constant initial velocity component turns more and more inwards. These are the most common conditions I think usually arise and these require very basic kinematics and dynamics .

Answer (score 0):

Pick two axes, $x$ in the direction of the velocity, $y$ perpendicular to velocity, but take care that the force vector be contained in the $x, y$ plane. Then the force makes with the velocity an angle $\theta$. The projection of the force on the velocity is $F_x = F cos(\theta)$, and the projection orthogonal to the velocity is $F_y = Fsin(\theta)$, s.t. the velocity projections are

(1) $v_x = v_0 + \int_{t_0}^t \frac {F(t) cos(\theta)}{m} dt$,

(2) $v_y = \int_{t_0}^t \frac {F(t) sin(\theta)}{m} dt$.

where I take the time at which the force was applied as $t_0$ and $v_0 = v(t_0)$ is the velocity before the force is applied. The angle $\alpha$ by which the direction of the velocity changes is given in any case by

(3) $tan (\alpha) = v_y/v_x$.

Now, if the case is that the force adjusts itself all the time so as to be perpendicular to $\vec v$, (see Phonix' question) then at the time $t = t_0 +dt$, we have

(4) $v_x(t_0 + dt) = v_0$,

(5) $v_y = \frac {F(t_0)}{m} dt$,

and $tan (\alpha)$ is according to (1)

(6) $tan (\alpha(t_0 + dt)) = \frac {F(t_0)}{m} \frac {dt}{v_0}$.

however, the force is along the direction

$\beta(t_0 + dt) = arctan(\frac {F}{m} \frac {dt}{v_0}) + \pi/2$,

or,

(7) $cotan(\beta(t_0 + dt)) = \frac {F}{m} \frac {dt}{v_0}$,

Now, we can apply the equations (1) and (2).

(8) $v_x = v_0 + \frac {F(t_0 +dt) cos(beta(t_0 + dt))}{m} dt$,

(9) $v_y = \frac {F(t_0)}{m} dt + \frac {F(t_0 + dt) sin(\theta)}{m} dt$.,

This is the tableau if the force varies I time. Maybe it can be simplified, but what I see is that the solution is iterative, because the force depends on both $t$ and $v$.

However, if the force is constant in magnitude, only always perpendicular to velocity the answer to your question is covered by the site [Rotation systems. Problem interpreting an equation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/148944/rotation-systems-problem-interpreting-an-equation/149303#149303) would be of further help.